# spectrum of a polygon and zeta function

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Let $\Delta(x,y) = 1,0$ according to whether $(x,y)$ is in some polygon (symmetric with respect to the diagonal axis).

E.g. The convex hull of three points (taken from a paper on [dominoes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0511287))

$$   \Delta = \bigg\{ r(-1,-1)+s(1,0)+t(0,1): r + s + t = 1\bigg\} $$

So I am looking for eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this Kernel:

$$ f \mapsto \int_{-1}^1 \Delta(x,\;\cdot\;) f(x)\;dx$$

This occurred to me while reading this paper by Noam Elkies on [zeta functions](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Elkies561-573.pdf), where he studies the spectrum of the convex hull:

$$ \bigg\{ r(0,0)+s(1,0)+t(0,1): r + s + t = 1\bigg\} $$

In that paper he gets a zeta function by taking the trace of this kernel,

$$ \mathrm{tr}(\Delta^n) =  \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \lambda_i^n $$

For Elkies, $\lambda_k = \frac{1}{4k+1}$.  See also the paper by [Stanley](http://www1.combinatorics.org/Volume_18/PDF/v18i2p16.pdf).

He then interprets the trace $\mathrm{tr}(\Delta^n)$ as the volume of a polytope, which I will address separately.